# How do I join portions of a list in Python

Tags: string, list, join, split

Trying to join only portions of a large list that has numbers in it.  For example:

```
h = ['9 This is the way this is the way 10 to program a string 11 to program a string']
##I've tried...
h[0].split()
z = []
h = ['9', 'This', 'is', 'the', 'way', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'way', '10', 'to', 'program', 'a', 'string', '11', 'to', 'program', 'a', 'string']
for i in h:
    while i != '10':
        z.append(i)
```

But the program runs an infinite loop.  I've also tried if statements, if i != '10' then z.append(i).  Basically, I have large portions of scripture that is in a list as a single string and I'd like to quickly extract the verses and put them in their own separate list.  Thank you

Edit: I've tried...

```
h= ['9 nfnf dhhd snsn nana na 10 hfhf gkg utu 11 oeoe ldd sss', 'kgk hfh']
y = h[0].split()
print (y)
z = []
for i in y:
    if i != "10":
       z.append(i)
       break
print (z)
```

Output is the split list and 'z' prints '9' only.  I've also changed the break to the correct indentation for the 'for' loop

Comment: Jesus dude. That's an infinite loop

Comment: If i =='10': break

Comment: Also. Why split and then not use the result?

Comment: You are using while instead of if statement here

Comment: @VeltzerDoron can you make sure my code is okay in my answer. Thanks

Comment: @rahulmehra even if he uses an if statement instead of the while statement and uses the same condition, it will still be wrong because it will append every item of h to z unless it is "10". I think OP is trying to append every item of h to z up until he gets to "10". Please read my answer and let me know if its okay.

Comment: @tlove777 try my new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use the result you get from `h[0].split()`. You can do this by using `h = h[0].split()`

Now, lets get to the loop. It's going into an infinite loop because the `for` loop is picking the first `i` which is `"9"` and then `while i != "10"`, it keeps appending `i` to `z`. `i` will never equal `"10"`. Thus, the infinite loop. I think what you want here is:

```
for i in h:
    if i != "10":
        z.append(i)
    else:
        break
```

This will append every value of h into z until i is equal to "10". Let me know if you need more help and I'll be happy to edit!

Comment: If you meant to add something after "So I tried this, with your suggestion:", i don't see it.

Comment: So, I tried it but it just returns the first iteration.  Such as '9'

Comment: @tlove777 10 must be a string. So use "10" not 10. and tell me if it works

Comment: tried it but still only returns "9" and won't add the other items.

Comment: @tlove777 i have edited it with an else statement. use that. i tried it works

Comment: I got it.  Forgot the else statement. Thank you!

Comment: @tlove777 sorry about that. when i copied the code from python to stackoverflow, it didn't copy properly and the else statement got lost. Really sorry about that. If I helped, make sure you accept my answer! :)

Comment: @tlove777 ^^ you can accept by clicking on the grey arrow next to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this for extracting all numbers in z:

```
h = ['9 This is the way this is the way 10 to program a string 11 to program a string']
##I've tried...
h = h[0].split()
z = []
for i in h:
    try:
        z.append(eval(i))
    except:
        pass

print z
```

output:

```
[9, 10, 11]
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: it looks like OP is new to programming. So it doesn't seem like he'll understand try and except statements.

Comment: Yes, I am new to programming lol.  This is only somewhat helpful as i need the output to be ['9 This is the way this is the way', '10 to program a string', '11 to program a string']